# Pygame labyrinth

Tags: python, pygame

I recently found a nice little labyrinth made using pygame and I had an idea : I want to replace all those ugly rectangles by :

- a background picture
- a sprite for the player
- a sprite for the walls

I already tried something but each time I tried it I had an error ( I can't post the code here because there's a bug when I try to upload it, it shows me that I didn't put the 4 indents but I did...)

Can somebody please point me in the right direction ? 
Here's the link to the original game :

http://www.pygame.org/project-Rect+Collision+Response-1061-.html

```
import pygame
import random
from pygame.locals import *
```

## Classe joueur / player Class

class Joueur(object):

```
def _init_(self):
    self.rect = pygame.image.load("perso.png").convert_alpha()

def mvmt(self, dx, dy):
    #déplacement sur un axe a la fois avec detection de collision / Move each axis separately. Note that this checks for collisions both times.
    if dx !=0:
        self.mvmt_axe(dx, 0)
    if dy !=0:
        self.mvmt_axe(0, dy)

def mvmt_axe(self, dx, dy):

    self.rect.x +=dx
    self.rect.y +=dy
    # Action en cas de collision /  If you collide with a wall, move out based on velocity
    for mur in murs :
        if self.rect.colliderect(mur.rect):
            if dx > 0 :
                self.rect.right = mur.rect.left
            if dx < 0 :
                self.rect.left = mur.rect.right
            if dy > 0 :
                self.rect.bottom = mur.rect.top
            if dy < 0 :
                self.rect.top = mur.rect.bottom
```

Comment: CAn you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Add the code even though it looks ugly and we'll help you fix it. Questions without code usually get closed pretty quickly.

Comment: the error is at the end of the code : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maxime\ISN 2014\Dropbox\Deadalus\Partie Maxime\proto collision.py", line 74, in <module>
    Mur((x, y))
TypeError: object() takes no parameters

Comment: Here's the link to my whole code : https://www.dropbox.com/s/b91jbq13qogd7a8/proto%20collision.py

Comment: The way that I have had to put in the code is to copy paste then put in the four spaces by hand on each line. If tab characters get copied in, then the formatting is still messed up. Make sure that you do not have any tab characters in the area that you copy.

Answer (score 1):

The dropbox shows a class Mur but the code in the question does not. I answered based on the error that you showed in the comments and the code that I saw in the dropbox. The difference appears to be the self.rect definition.

However, please recheck the code that you are executing. the error shows that

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Maxime\ISN 2014\Dropbox\Deadalus\Partie Maxime\proto collision.py", line 74, in  Mur((x, y)) TypeError: object() takes no parameters

This appears to mean that the change that you have made in defining self.rect at line 40 has changed the definition sufficiently to make Mur no longer accept the call setting. Please check that the original code does work properly as well. Also check that the line 74 in the dropbox is what you are running as

```
Mur(x, y)
```

and

```
Mur((x, y))
```

are different enough to cause a failure.

In the your code you have

```
#Classe mur / Class for the wall ( it will be represented by a small .png 

class Mur(object):
  def _init_(self, pos): 
    murs.append(self) 
    # Put in a print statement here
    self.rect = pygame.image.load("mur.png").convert_alpha() # line 40
```

Line 74 is

```
#Création du niveau après 'lecture' des murs / Parse the level string above. M = wall, S = exit  line 69
x = y = 0                 # This is line 70
for rangée in niveau:     # This is line 71
  for colonne in rangée:  # This is line 72
    if colonne == "M":    # This is line 73
        Mur((x, y))       # This is line 74 and is the error
    if colonnne == "S": 
        end_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 30, 30) 
    x += 30
  y += 30
  x = 0
```

I compared the dropbox to the original

## Nice class to hold a wall rect

class Wall(object):

```
def __init__(self, pos):
    walls.append(self)
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 16, 16)

# Parse the level string above. W = wall, E = exit
x = y = 0
for row in level:
  for col in row:
    if col == "W":
        Wall((x, y))
    if col == "E":
        end_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 16, 16)
    x += 16
  y += 16
  x = 0
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but can you explain it a little further ( I'm only a beginner so...)

Comment: @MaxFR68 Did the additions that I made help?

Comment: it still shows me the error . Would you please show me what the correct line would be ?

Comment: @MaxFR68 I do not have access to a Linux platform now so that all I can do is try to analyze on my Windoze machine. This makes it hard to try to install python scripts. If I had access to a real computer, I would run the original code that you point to and make sure that that script works. If that does not work, then it is the problem of the original. If that runs and yours does not, check if changing the one line in Mur makes a difference. Also double check if you ran Mur(object) or Mur()

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll look into it ( my next IT lesson is scheduled on friday so...) Btw, what was that comment about "real computer" ? Windows is great ! ( Especially 8.1 ;)

Comment: @MaxFR68 "I don't do windows" I am prejudiced back to the days of DOS. In any case how does one take the example and copy it in to a windows machine and actually run it. I can do it with Unix (of any flavor) but am not sure how to do it with Windows. From the first line of the original, I see that it is a Unix script.